# Concatenate/append file downloaded from FTP server to one file

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Not able to understand how I can use APPEND functionality in the `GetFiles()` method. I have to append multiple files and download it as single file in my local machine. Will this APPEND functionality work?

The code is:

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Reading and Storing from configuration File
$csv = Import-Csv "Configuration.csv"
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Hostname = $_.hostname
    $username = $_.username
    $Password = $_.Password
    $hostkey = $_.hostkey
    $Existingfilepath = $_.Existingfilepath
    $newfilepath = $_.newfilepath
    $localpath = $_.localpath
}

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $Hostname
    UserName = $username
    Password = $Password
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = $hostkey
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Download files
    $session.GetFiles($Existingfilepath, $localpath).Check()

    # Move Files from Upload to Archive Folder
    $session.MoveFile($Existingfilepath,$newfilepath)
} finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

---

**Edit:** I have put the `Get-Files` under `$csv | ForEach-Object`.

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
#Reading and Storing from configuration File
$csv = Import-Csv "Configuration.csv"
$opts = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$opts.TransferMode  = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
$opts.OverwriteMode = [WinSCP.OverwriteMode]::Append

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Hostname = $_.hostname
    $username =$_.username
    $Password = $_.Password
    $hostkey = $_.hostkey
    $Existingfilepath = $_.Existingfilepath
    $newfilepath = $_.newfilepath
    $localpath= $_.localpath

    # Download files
    $session.GetFiles($Existingfilepath, $localpath, $false, $opts).Check()
}
# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $Hostname
    UserName = $username
    Password = $Password
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = $hostkey
}
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Move Files from Upload to Archive Folder
    $session.MoveFile($Existingfilepath,$newfilepath)
} finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

*MERGED FILE LOGS*

```
. 2017-10-25 17:04:35.570 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-10-25 17:04:35.570 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:35.570 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2017-10-25 17:04:35.570 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 114, Number: -1
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 SFTP versions supported by the server: 2,3
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 Getting current directory name.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 Getting real path for '.'
> 2017-10-25 17:04:36.085 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2017-10-25 17:04:36.709 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 107, Number: 16
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.709 Real path is '/'
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.709 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2017-10-25 17:04:36.709 Script: Active session: [1] abcbank@sftpabcbank.learn.taleo.net
> 2017-10-25 17:04:36.756 Script: pwd
< 2017-10-25 17:04:36.756 Script: /
> 2017-10-25 17:04:36.818 Script: get  -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer="binary" -append -- "/upload/attendance*.csv" "C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc-Bank\Transfer Files\abc Bank Attendance Files\attendance.csv"
. 2017-10-25 17:04:36.818 Listing directory "/upload".
> 2017-10-25 17:04:36.818 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 16, Number: 267
< 2017-10-25 17:04:37.411 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 267
> 2017-10-25 17:04:37.411 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 524
< 2017-10-25 17:04:37.832 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 673, Number: 524
> 2017-10-25 17:04:37.832 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 780
< 2017-10-25 17:04:38.144 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 33, Number: 780
< 2017-10-25 17:04:38.144 Status code: 1
> 2017-10-25 17:04:38.144 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 1028
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 Archive;d;0;2017-10-25T11:34:14.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 attendance v2-201709220930.csv;-;8815;2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 attendance v2-201709220931.csv;-;8512;2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 bulkloader;d;0;2017-09-20T11:54:37.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 userIntegration;d;0;2017-07-26T16:51:13.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T05:30:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
< 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 Script: Are you sure you want to transfer multiple files to a single file 'attendance.csv' in a directory 'C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc-Bank\Transfer Files\abc Bank Attendance Files\'?
< 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 The files will overwrite one another.
< 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 If you actually want to transfer all files to a directory 'C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc-Bank\Transfer Files\abc Bank Attendance Files\attendance.csv\', keeping their name, make sure you terminate the path with a slash.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 Copying 2 files/directories to local directory "C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc-Bank\Transfer Files\abc Bank Attendance Files\" - total size: 17,327
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: attendance.csv
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 File: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv' [2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z] [8815]
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 Copying "/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv" to local directory started.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 Opening remote file.
> 2017-10-25 17:04:38.160 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 55, Number: 1283
< 2017-10-25 17:04:38.550 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1028
. 2017-10-25 17:04:38.550 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:04:38.955 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 1283
> 2017-10-25 17:04:38.955 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 15, Number: 1544
< 2017-10-25 17:04:39.564 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 1544
> 2017-10-25 17:04:39.579 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 27, Number: 1797
< 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Status code: 1
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 3 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 2308
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Preserving timestamp [2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z]
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Transfer done: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv' => 'C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc\Transfer Files\Attendance Files\attendance.csv' [8815]
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 File: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv' [2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z] [8512]
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Copying "/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv" to local directory started.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Opening remote file.
> 2017-10-25 17:04:41.066 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 55, Number: 2563
< 2017-10-25 17:04:41.722 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 2308
. 2017-10-25 17:04:41.722 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:04:42.034 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 2563
> 2017-10-25 17:04:42.034 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 15, Number: 2824
< 2017-10-25 17:04:42.689 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 2824
. 2017-10-25 17:04:42.689 Confirming overwriting of file.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:42.689 Appending to file.
> 2017-10-25 17:04:42.689 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 27, Number: 3077
< 2017-10-25 17:04:43.672 Status code: 1
. 2017-10-25 17:04:43.672 3 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2017-10-25 17:04:43.672 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 3588
. 2017-10-25 17:04:43.672 Preserving timestamp [2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z]
. 2017-10-25 17:04:43.672 Transfer done: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv' => 'C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc\Transfer Files\abc\attendance.csv' [8512]
. 2017-10-25 17:04:43.672 Copying finished: Transferred: 17,327, Elapsed: 0:00:05, CPS: 2,687/s
> 2017-10-25 17:04:44.124 Script: mv "/upload/attendance*.csv" "/upload/Archive/attendance*.csv"
. 2017-10-25 17:04:44.124 Listing directory "/upload".
> 2017-10-25 17:04:44.124 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 16, Number: 3851
< 2017-10-25 17:04:44.483 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 3588
. 2017-10-25 17:04:44.483 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:04:45.403 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 3851
> 2017-10-25 17:04:45.403 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 4108
< 2017-10-25 17:04:45.809 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 673, Number: 4108
> 2017-10-25 17:04:45.809 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 4364
< 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 33, Number: 4364
< 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 Status code: 1
> 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 4612
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 Archive;d;0;2017-10-25T11:34:14.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 attendance v2-201709220930.csv;-;8815;2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 attendance v2-201709220931.csv;-;8512;2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 bulkloader;d;0;2017-09-20T11:54:37.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 userIntegration;d;0;2017-07-26T16:51:13.000Z;3;"abcbank" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T05:30:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 Moving file "/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv" to "/upload/Archive/attendance v2-201709220930.csv".
> 2017-10-25 17:04:46.230 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 97, Number: 4882
< 2017-10-25 17:04:46.948 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 4612
. 2017-10-25 17:04:46.948 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:04:47.244 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 4882
< 2017-10-25 17:04:47.244 Status code: 0
< 2017-10-25 17:04:47.244 Script: /upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv
. 2017-10-25 17:04:47.244 Moving file "/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv" to "/upload/Archive/attendance v2-201709220931.csv".
> 2017-10-25 17:04:47.244 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 97, Number: 5138
< 2017-10-25 17:04:47.868 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 5138
< 2017-10-25 17:04:47.868 Status code: 0
< 2017-10-25 17:04:47.868 Script: /upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv
> 2017-10-25 17:04:49.553 Script: exit
. 2017-10-25 17:04:49.553 Script: Exit code: 0
. 2017-10-25 17:04:49.553 Closing connection.
. 2017-10-25 17:04:49.553 Sending special code: 12
. 2017-10-25 17:04:49.553 Sent EOF message
```

*SEPARATE FILE LOG*

```
. 2017-10-25 17:06:10.986 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-10-25 17:06:10.986 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:10.986 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2017-10-25 17:06:10.986 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 114, Number: -1
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 SFTP versions supported by the server: 2,3
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 Getting current directory name.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 Getting real path for '.'
> 2017-10-25 17:06:11.735 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2017-10-25 17:06:12.374 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 107, Number: 16
. 2017-10-25 17:06:12.374 Real path is '/'
. 2017-10-25 17:06:12.374 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2017-10-25 17:06:12.374 Script: Active session: [1] abc.net
> 2017-10-25 17:06:12.874 Script: pwd
< 2017-10-25 17:06:12.874 Script: /
> 2017-10-25 17:06:12.936 Script: get  -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer="binary" -append -- "/upload/attendance*.csv" "C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc\Transfer Files\abc\attendance*.csv"
. 2017-10-25 17:06:12.936 Listing directory "/upload".
> 2017-10-25 17:06:12.936 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 16, Number: 267
< 2017-10-25 17:06:13.576 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 267
> 2017-10-25 17:06:13.576 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 524
< 2017-10-25 17:06:14.028 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 673, Number: 524
> 2017-10-25 17:06:14.028 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 780
< 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 33, Number: 780
< 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 Status code: 1
> 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 1028
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 Archive;d;0;2017-10-25T11:35:40.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 attendance v2-201709220930.csv;-;8815;2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 attendance v2-201709220931.csv;-;8512;2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 bulkloader;d;0;2017-09-20T11:54:37.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 userIntegration;d;0;2017-07-26T16:51:13.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T05:30:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387 Copying 2 files/directories to local directory "C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc\Transfer Files\abc\" - total size: 17,327
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.387   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: attendance*.csv
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.402   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.402   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.402 File: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv' [2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z] [8815]
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.402 Copying "/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv" to local directory started.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.402 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.402 Opening remote file.
> 2017-10-25 17:06:14.402 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 55, Number: 1283
< 2017-10-25 17:06:14.699 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1028
. 2017-10-25 17:06:14.699 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:06:14.995 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 1283
> 2017-10-25 17:06:14.995 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 15, Number: 1544
< 2017-10-25 17:06:15.588 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 1544
> 2017-10-25 17:06:15.588 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 27, Number: 1797
< 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Status code: 1
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 3 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 2308
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Preserving timestamp [2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z]
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Transfer done: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv' => 'C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc\Transfer Files\abc\attendance v2-201709220930.csv' [8815]
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 File: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv' [2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z] [8512]
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Copying "/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv" to local directory started.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Opening remote file.
> 2017-10-25 17:06:16.540 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 55, Number: 2563
< 2017-10-25 17:06:16.836 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 2308
. 2017-10-25 17:06:16.836 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:06:17.164 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 2563
> 2017-10-25 17:06:17.164 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 15, Number: 2824
< 2017-10-25 17:06:17.866 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 2824
> 2017-10-25 17:06:17.881 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 27, Number: 3077
< 2017-10-25 17:06:19.004 Status code: 1
. 2017-10-25 17:06:19.004 3 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2017-10-25 17:06:19.004 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 3588
. 2017-10-25 17:06:19.004 Preserving timestamp [2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z]
. 2017-10-25 17:06:19.004 Transfer done: '/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv' => 'C:\Ratnesh\Projects\abc\Transfer Files\abc\attendance v2-201709220931.csv' [8512]
. 2017-10-25 17:06:19.004 Copying finished: Transferred: 17,327, Elapsed: 0:00:04, CPS: 3,082/s
> 2017-10-25 17:06:19.426 Script: mv "/upload/attendance*.csv" "/upload/Archive/attendance*.csv"
. 2017-10-25 17:06:19.426 Listing directory "/upload".
> 2017-10-25 17:06:19.426 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 16, Number: 3851
< 2017-10-25 17:06:19.613 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 3588
. 2017-10-25 17:06:19.613 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:06:19.909 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 15, Number: 3851
> 2017-10-25 17:06:19.909 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 4108
< 2017-10-25 17:06:20.330 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 673, Number: 4108
> 2017-10-25 17:06:20.330 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 15, Number: 4364
< 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 33, Number: 4364
< 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 Status code: 1
> 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 15, Number: 4612
. 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 Archive;d;0;2017-10-25T11:35:40.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 attendance v2-201709220930.csv;-;8815;2017-10-05T14:26:50.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 attendance v2-201709220931.csv;-;8512;2017-10-18T08:16:06.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 bulkloader;d;0;2017-09-20T11:54:37.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 userIntegration;d;0;2017-07-26T16:51:13.000Z;3;"abc" [2222];"ftp" [2222];rwxrwx---;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T05:30:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 Moving file "/upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv" to "/upload/Archive/attendance v2-201709220930.csv".
> 2017-10-25 17:06:20.674 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 97, Number: 4882
< 2017-10-25 17:06:21.251 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 4612
. 2017-10-25 17:06:21.251 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-10-25 17:06:21.625 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 4882
< 2017-10-25 17:06:21.625 Status code: 0
< 2017-10-25 17:06:21.625 Script: /upload/attendance v2-201709220930.csv
. 2017-10-25 17:06:21.625 Moving file "/upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv" to "/upload/Archive/attendance v2-201709220931.csv".
> 2017-10-25 17:06:21.625 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 97, Number: 5138
< 2017-10-25 17:06:22.174 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 5138
< 2017-10-25 17:06:22.174 Status code: 0
< 2017-10-25 17:06:22.174 Script: /upload/attendance v2-201709220931.csv
> 2017-10-25 17:06:22.267 Script: exit
. 2017-10-25 17:06:22.267 Script: Exit code: 0
. 2017-10-25 17:06:22.267 Closing connection.
. 2017-10-25 17:06:22.267 Sending special code: 12
. 2017-10-25 17:06:22.267 Sent EOF message
```

[image: Configuration File Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles). The `GetFiles()` method takes up to 4 arguments:

> ```
> public TransferOperationResult GetFiles(
>     string remotePath,
>     string localPath,
>     bool remove = false,
>     TransferOptions options = null
> )
> ```

You need to pass the `Append` transfer option as the 4th parameter. If your CSV contains more than one record you also need to put the `GetFiles()` call in the loop processing the CSV data.

Something like this should work (untested, though):

```
$opts = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$opts.TransferMode  = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
$opts.OverwriteMode = [WinSCP.OverwriteMode]::Append

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    ...
    $session.GetFiles($Existingfilepath, $localpath, $false, $opts).Check()
}
```

Note that this will only append to the *local* file. On the remote host you'll still have multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ansgar has already suggested, you can use [`OverwriteMode.Append`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#overwritemode) to concatenate files.

A full code would be like:

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Reading from configuration File
$csv = Import-Csv "Configuration.csv"
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # Set up session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = $_.HostName
        UserName = $_.UserName
        Password = $_.Password
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = $_.HostKey
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Download and append file
        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.OverwriteMode = [WinSCP.OverwriteMode]::Append

        $session.GetFiles(
            $_.ExistingFilePath, $_.LocalPath, $False, $transferOptions).Check()

        # Move Files from Upload to Archive Folder
        $session.MoveFile($_.ExistingFilePath, $_.NewFilePath)
    }
    finally
    {
        $session.Dispose()
    }
}
```

---

*Though note that this way, you will open a new connection for each file. If all files are actually on the same server, you should consider separating a  server configuration from a file list, to allow using a single connection.*